# Turtle laying his head restlessly against glass

Tags: behavior, reptiles, turtles

I have had a turtle for about 2 weeks now, and today I noticed him laying his head against the glass, which I did not see him do earlier. I am quite new to reptiles and I am a bit worried. I have also noticed him being quite nervous when I try to pick him up. He did not do this before. Is this normal?

I feed him vegetables, bloodworms and dried river shrimp. I also dust them once in a while with calcium powder with vitamin D<sub>3</sub>.

Comment: I feel like we need a template for reptile questions lol need some extra info here. Can you post pictures of your setup aswell as temps and lighting specs?

Comment: i am still waiting for his uv bulb to come through and currently he has a long lamp for fish, for some reason i am unable to download the pics

Comment: Maybe he's overheating and trying to cool off by touching the glass. Does he have water and shade, and is the tank the right temperature.

Comment: Do not dust the food with calcium. In this way the turtle can not choose the right intake.of calcium itself. Instead one can give a cuttlebone of a sepia (offered for birds) floating in the tank. The turtle could itself bite parts of it.

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be a husbandry issue is stressing him somewhat. Look up a caresheet at what temps, humidity, and environment he needs. Im not familiar with turtles so i cant answer more than that